# Is there an API to see how flow files are being processed by the 'origen program' command?

Tags: origen-sdk

If I pass multiple flow files to the Origen `progam` command as so:

```
origen p flow_file1 flow_file2 flow_file3
```

Is there an API to see the queue real-time in the test interface?  I see there is a [`current_command` API](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen.html#current_command-class_method) but it doesn't contain any information about the number of flow files being processed.  Something along the lines of:

```
Origen.commands.queue # => ['flow_file1', 'flow_file2', 'flow_file3']
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently available, but it should not be hard to add if you want it.

Internally, the list of files is held in an anonymous array returned by this call to `expand_lists_and_directories` - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/60746ae33fd813b8cf1a3624f985476138a59920/lib/origen/application/runner.rb#L85

You could capture that into a named array and then make a read method for it.